# Why this particular test could be useful?

Tags: c#, tdd

I recently joined a company where they use TDD, but it's still not clear for me, for example, we have a test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldReturnGameIsRunning()
{
    var game = new Mock<IGame>();
    game.Setup(g => g.IsRunning).Returns(true);
    Assert.IsTrue(game.Object.IsRunning);
}
```

What's the purpose of it? As far as I understand, this is testing nothing! I say that because it's mocking an interface, and saying, return true for IsRunning, it will never return a different value...

I'm probably thinking wrong, as everybody says it's a good practice etc etc... or is this test wrong?

Comment: Usually rests are not this pointless.

Comment: You have two different things going on in this question - "What's the purpose of TDD?" and "What's the point of this test?" - be careful to keep the two separate in your own head. The value (or not) of TDD can't be fairly judged from a single (possibly poor) test.

Comment: I wish I could close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdd?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: Voting to reopen on grounds of "why this particular test could be useful" - produced some good respones (if decided to reopen - last person please make sure to change title).

Comment: This should have been edited to refer just to the specific test, rather than closing it as "not constructive", which isn't true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test is invalid. [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) is a framework used to "mock" objects used by the method under test. If you were testing `IsRunning`, you might use Mock to provide a certain implementation for those methods that `IsRunning` depends on, for example to cause certain execution paths to execute.

People can tell you all day that testing first is better; you won't realize that it actually is until you start doing it yourself and realize that you have fewer bugs with code you wrote tests for first, which will save you and your co-workers time and probably make the quality of your code higher.

Comment: hmm I suspected that... there is a implementation of the IGame interface that is not tested at all, that's why I don't get the idea of this...

Comment: there is no sense of having another implementation of the IGame interface, they should be testing the Game object instead of the interface, right? How about driving the design of the code? I mean, how should I define that there must be a IsRunning property?

Comment: @user1082693: Right. Now if you were testing a method's behavior based on certain return values of `IGame`'s method's, Moq would certainly come in handy--creating a whole new subclass of `IGame` just for testing purposes would prove painful. As for testing for a certain property, I would let code constructs like interfaces and abstract classes enforce those rules.

Answer (score 6):

This test is excerising an interface, and verifying that the interface exposes a Boolean getter named `IsRunning`.

This test was probably written before the `interface` existed, and probably well before any concrete classes of `IGame` existed either. I would imagine, if the project is of any maturity, there are other tests that exercise the actual implementions and verify behavior for that level, and probably use mocking in the more traditional isolationist context rather than stubbing theoretical shapes.

The value of these kinds of tests is that it forces one to think about how a shape or object is going to be used. Something along the lines of "I don't know exactly what a game is going to do yet, but I do know that I'm going to want to check if it's running...". So this style of testing is more to drive design decisions, as well as validate behavior.

Not the most valuable test on the planet, but serves its purpose in my opinion.

*Edit*: I was on the train last night when I was typing this, but I wanted to address Andrew Whitaker comment directly in the answer.

One could argue that the signature in the interface itself is enough of an enforcement of the desired contract. However, this really depends on how you treat your interfaces and ultimately how you validate the system that you are trying to test.

There may be tangible value in explicitly stating this functionality as a test. You are explicitly verifying that this is a desired functionality for an `IGame`.

Lets take a use case, lets say that as a designer you know that you want to expose a public getter for `IsRunning`, so you add it to the interface. But lets say that another developer gets this and sees a property, but doesn't see any usages of it anywhere else in the code, one might assume that it is eligible for deletion (or code-rot removal, which is normally a good thing) without harm. The existence of this test, however, explicitly states this properity should exist.

Without this test, a developer could modify the interface, drop the implementation and the project would still compile and run seemingly correctly. And it would be until much later that someone might notice that interface has been changed.

With this test, even if it appears as if no one is using it, your test suite will fail. The self documenting nature of the test tells you that `ShouldReturnGameIsRunning()`, which at the very least should spawn a conversation if `IGame` should really expose an `IsRunning` getter.

Comment: cool I get it... I'll ask them tomorrow, so it should probably be to drive the design, and then I should create more tests to test the logic, right?

Comment: @32bitkid: This might just be my opinion, but isn't a test overkill for this? Wouldn't simply defining a signature for the method in the interface create the "contract" that this test is testing for?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker. I think it depends on how you think about validating the system you are trying to test. There may be some value in explicitly stating this as a test that this is a desired functionality for an `IGame`. If it were signature only, if on one use it anywhere it may appear as if it could be removed without harm. This test explicitly states this properity should exist. If it doesn't, even if noone is usining it, your tests will fail

Comment: +1 for very insightful answer, rather than taking the easy route of writing the test off as "invalid" or "useless". Even if this isn't the intention behind this test, it could have been.

Comment: @user1082693 that is definitely correct. You'll want some tests that actually exercise and validate the behavior of your implementations as well. This test is validating design decisions, where as the other test will validate unit behavior.

Comment: I buy your argument, to an extent; however if they are really using TDD, then if that property isn't used by a concrete implementation somewhere, or in another test, it shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @Mathias To reiterate, I'm not saying this is the best test ever, or that its a great idea and everybody should do it. But I am saying that the test is validating something, it is *in fact* testing something. Its not something that I would do, unless I had a very specific reason for doing it (perhaps validating an publicly facing interface in a library class).

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the test has been written (before) the code which is good practice.

It might equally be that this is a pointless test created by a tool.

Comment: I don't think there is any tool that creates the test here, so it's probably that they wrote the test before the code then.. hmmm

Comment: Depends on your definition of "tool"!  :)

Comment: +1 and we could mean either popular meaning of the word "tool" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the code was written by somebody who, at the time, didn't understand how to use that particular mocking framework - and wrote one or more simple tests to learn. Kent Beck talked about that sort of "learning test" in his original TDD book.

Answer (score 0):

This test could have had a point in the past. It could have been testing a concrete class. It could have been testing an abstract one -- as it sometimes makes sense to mock an abstract class that you want to test. I can see how a (less informed(like myself)) follower of the TDD way of doing things could have left a small mess like this. Cleanup of dead code and dead test code, does not really fit in the natural workflow of red, green, refactor (since it doesn't break any tests!). 
However, history is not justification for a test that does nothing but confuse the reader. So, be a good boyscout and  remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In my honest oppinion this is just rubbish, it only proves that moq works as expected